# Github GraphQL to recursively list all files in the directory

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I want to use the GraphQL Github API to recursively list all files contained in the directory. Right now my query looks like this:

```
{
  search(first:1, type: REPOSITORY, query: "language:C") {
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          name
          descriptionHTML
          stargazers {
            totalCount
          }
          forks {
            totalCount
          }
          object(expression: "master:") {
            ... on Tree {
              entries {
                name
                type
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this only gives me only the first level of directory contents, in particular some of the resulting objects are again trees. Is there a way to adjust the query, such that it recursively list the contents of tree again?

Comment: I was excited to see your question, both because your example solved an issue I was having with GraphQL AND because I thought I knew of a solution. Sadly, when I attempted to use a "fragment," it threw an error about "Fragment [fragment name] contains an infinite loop. So now I'm anxiously awaiting an answer to this question, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to recursively iterate in GraphQL. However, you can do so programmatically using a query variable:

```
query TestQuery($branch: GitObjectID) {
 search(first: 1, type: REPOSITORY, query: "language:C") {
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          object(expression: "master:", oid: $branch) {
            ... on Tree {
              entries {
                oid
                name
                type
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Start with a value of `null` and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

working [example](https://sourcegraph.com/api/console#%7B%22query%22%3A%22query%20ListFiles(%24repoName%3A%20String!)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20repository(name%3A%20%24repoName)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20commit(rev%3A%20%5C%22HEAD%5C%22)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20tree(path%3A%20%5C%22docs%5C%22%2C%20recursive%3A%20true)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entries%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isDirectory%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22variables%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20%5C%22repoName%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22github.com%2Fexoframejs%2Fexoframe%5C%22%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22operationName%22%3A%22ListFiles%22%7D)

More info: https://docs.sourcegraph.com/api/graphql/examples

But probably this will change in the near feature. For example latest github version is v4  https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/

Comment: It still works, however in the Github GraphQl Explorer I get two errors with your example: `"Field 'repository' is missing required arguments: owner"` and `"Field 'commit' doesn't exist on type 'Repository'"`

Comment: The first error from my comment one hour ago can be solved by using `owner`, but the second one seems not to be cleared. Another query is needed to work with the explorer?

Answer (score -1):

```
{
  search(first: 1, type: REPOSITORY, query: "language:C") {
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          name
          descriptionHTML
          stargazers {
            totalCount
          }
          forks {
            totalCount
          }
          object(expression: "master:") {
            ... on Tree {
              entries {
                name
                object {
                  ... on Tree {
                    entries {
                      name
                      object {
                        ... on Tree {
                          entries {
                            name
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add a few words explaining what you are doing, to me it does not look recursive. It looks like you only go a few more levels deep